# What are the differences between the two available pizza elements?

Tags: piece-information, bricks-and-pieces

In the "Buy pieces" section of the Lego website, I looked up the pizza element. It turns out there are actually two of them!

Element 6102555 costs $0.41/piece and 81867 costs $0.37/piece, but they have identical images on the website.

What are the differences between these pieces, if any? (Other than the fact that one is 4 cents cheaper than the other!)

Comment: There's [a third pizza element](https://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=4150pb165&name=Tile,%20Round%202%20x%202%20with%20Pizza%20Pepperoni%20Pattern&category=%5BTile,%20Round,%20Decorated%5D#T=C) which is on a different colour tile and with a different print.

Comment: One's a pepperoni while the other's a bolognese?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bricklink tells me that 6102555 is [Tile, Round 2 x 2 with Bottom Stud Holder with Pizza Pattern](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?id=127984) and 81867 is [Tile, Round 2 x 2 with Pizza Pattern](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?id=1218) which according to the 3D model is the old style with the X on the bottom. Other than that, they seem to be identical.

Comment: If you need justification to choose one over the other, it's probably easier to make a minifig hold the 6102555 piece than it is to hold the other piece.

Answer (score 1):

They have different printings, although the website posts the same images.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dark tan pizza and a yellow pizza. The dark tan one comes with the pizza boy in the series 12 minifigs.

Comment: Yes, I have one of the tan pizzas as well. It's a different element than the other two yellow ones.